# ¿Es más eficiente pasar nativos o un objeto con JS en SocketIO?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando montar algo con SocketIO.js, y ando mandando mensajes entre cliente y servidor. Me gustaría saber qué es más eficiente a la hora de la transmisión: ¿Mandar varios parámetros nativos, un array, o un objeto con esos parámetros?

Se que a la hora de programarlo es más cómodo lo último, pero lo prioritario es reducir la carga de red.

La estructura es 1 servidor, multiples clientes en broadcast.

Ejemplo:

1 pasando nativos

```
client.on('action', function(intOne,intTwo,stringOne,intThree,floatOne,stringTwo)
    {
        client.broadcast.emit('clientAction',intOne,intTwo,stringOne,intThree,floatOne,stringTwo);
    });
```

2 Array y object

```
client.on('action', function(allParametersEncapsulated)
    {
        client.broadcast.emit('clientAction',allParametersEncapsulated);
    });
```

Comment: He intentado etiquetar SocketIO.js, pero no me deja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto explica que un array es más veloz que un object, y ya de paso, que objetos es más rápido que un array asociativo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295056/array-vs-object-efficiency-in-javascript

Este enlace dice que parámetros es menos costoso que un objeto.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325554/javascript-functions-and-arguments-object-is-there-a-cost-involved

Y... ya que un array en javascript es un array de strings (u objects si los metes) que traduce a sus respectivos tipos nativos, imagino que será más pesado que parametros.